# Hibernate + SQL Server Performance variable

Tags: sql, performance, hibernate, amazon-web-services, tomcat

I am having some performance trouble in our production server.

1) The principal query takes generally 0.5 secs, but sometimes it takes 20 secs, (then the client goes crazy because it's seems that crashed). The query is over a view and it does not have any eager or lazy object attached, only plain attributes. The query returns 100 paginated records (over 65.000 records)

Why is so variable? How can I improve the query, as the query is working fine most of the times?

2) Generally, the Javamelody stats show that server uses between 5 and 10 connections at same time. But sometimes this goes up to the max (100) and then the server goes busy and unstable.

We are having between 1800 and 2000 sessions working on the app.

This is my config:

**Tomcat Server:** AWS Linux EC2 Instance t2.medium

**MS SQL Server:** AWS Windows EC2 Instance c4.large (it has a SQL Server Express and now we are moving to an SQL Server Web Edition to get more powerful [maybe this is the problem?])

**JDBC Connection Pooling Configuration:**

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" id="dataSource">
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://url..."/>
   <property name="username" value="username..."/>
   <property name="password" value="password..."/>
   <property name="initialSize" value="10"/>
   <property name="maxTotal" value="100"/>
   <property name="maxIdle" value="50"/>
   <property name="minIdle" value="10"/>
</bean>
```

Should I change connection pooling config? How can I improve these leaks?

Thank you, and sorry for my english.

Comment: Gather wait stats for over a day continously,then you will be in a position to do some analysis

Comment: check this links:http://www.sqlsentry.com/white-papers/troubleshooting-sql-server-wait-stats   ..http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that 5 to 10 jdbc connections used at the same time, with queries taking about 0.5s is a lot. That's a clear indication that the database is certainly heavy loaded, even more so when having only 2 vcpu.

Queries taking sometimes 20s, instead of 0.5s, is just when the database has severe difficulties to keep up with the load: they are put waiting in queue.
And used jdbc connections increasing to 100 is when the database just "gives up": imagine 100 queries at the same time, when it already has difficulties to keep up with 5 to 10 queries at the same time.

In this case, sql queries should be optimized or the database server should changed.